# Show the full list of books with a flag if they have already been purchased

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is the book catalog and the other is the id of books sold per user. I need to show that user the complete catalog of books and if they already purchased one then a purchased flag.

```
select cat_books.name from cat_books
left join books_sold on cat_books.idbook = books_sold.idbook
where iduser = xxx;
```

Currently I only get the list of books that the user already bought but I don't know how to add the rest of the books that the user could buy

cat_books

```
| idbook | name  |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | book1 |
| 2      | book2 |
| 3      | book3 |
| 4      | book4 |
```

books_sold

```
| id_sold | idbook | iduser |
+---------+--------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |1       |
| 2       | 2      |1       |
| 3       | 1      |2       |
| 4       | 1      |3       |
```

expect data for iduser 1

```
| name  | sold_flag |
+-------+-----------+
| book1 | true      |
| book2 | true      |
| book3 | false     |
| book4 | false     |
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please correct your tags.

Comment: Where are the columns pertaining to the user?

Comment: It will be easier with some data schema and sample date, also a expect output will be nice.

Comment: You will need users table also in your query

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by cross joining the users to books to get the books they could buy then joining to books_sold and testing if they did buy. In this example I assume you are on mysql version 8 or above and I use a cte.

```
drop table if exists cat_books,books_sold;
CREATE TABLE cat_books
( idbook int, name  varchar(10));
insert into cat_books values
( 1      , 'book1' ),
( 2      , 'book2' ),
( 3      , 'book3' ),
( 4      , 'book4' );

create table books_sold
(id_sold int, idbook int, iduser int);
insert into books_sold values
( 1       , 1      ,1       ),
( 2       , 2      ,1       ),
( 3       , 1      ,2       ),
( 4       , 1      ,3       );

with cte as
(
select distinct iduser,cat_books.idbook 
from   books_sold
cross join cat_books
)
select *,
         case when id_sold is null then 'false' else 'true' end truefalse 
from cte
left join books_sold on books_sold.idbook = cte.idbook and cte.iduser = books_sold.iduser
join cat_books on cat_books.idbook = cte.idbook
order by cte.iduser,cte.idbook;


+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
| iduser | idbook | id_sold | idbook | iduser | idbook | name  | truefalse |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
|      1 |      1 |       1 |      1 |      1 |      1 | book1 | true      |
|      1 |      2 |       2 |      2 |      1 |      2 | book2 | true      |
|      1 |      3 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      3 | book3 | false     |
|      1 |      4 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      4 | book4 | false     |
|      2 |      1 |       3 |      1 |      2 |      1 | book1 | true      |
|      2 |      2 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      2 | book2 | false     |
|      2 |      3 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      3 | book3 | false     |
|      2 |      4 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      4 | book4 | false     |
|      3 |      1 |       4 |      1 |      3 |      1 | book1 | true      |
|      3 |      2 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      2 | book2 | false     |
|      3 |      3 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      3 | book3 | false     |
|      3 |      4 |    NULL |   NULL |   NULL |      4 | book4 | false     |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
12 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```